# wrong values at adder output in verilog module

Tags: verilog, vlsi, digital-design

I have written a gate level code for adder in Verilog. The output the adder is shown below. As you can see the sum and cout are always in z. I don't know why. Could you check what am I missing ? Thanks for your time.

OUTPUT:

a = x, b = x, cin = x, summ = z, cout = z at time = 0

a = 0, b = 0, cin = 0, summ = z, cout = z at time = 10

a = 0, b = 1, cin = 0, summ = z, cout = z at time = 20

a = 1, b = 0, cin = 0, summ = z, cout = z at time = 30

a = 1, b = 1, cin = 0, summ = z, cout = z at time = 40

a = 0, b = 0, cin = 1, summ = z, cout = z at time = 50

a = 0, b = 1, cin = 1, summ = z, cout = z at time = 60

a = 1, b = 0, cin = 1, summ = z, cout = z at time = 70

a = 1, b = 1, cin = 1, summ = z, cout = z at time = 80

```
module tb();  

reg a, b, cin; 
wire cout, summ;


FA_gatelevel gatelevel(.a(a), .b(b), .cin(cin), .summ(summ), .cout(cout));

initial begin  

    #10 a = 0; b = 0; cin = 0; 
    #10 a = 0; b = 1; cin = 0;
    #10 a = 1; b = 0; cin = 0;
    #10 a = 1; b = 1; cin = 0;
    #10 a = 0; b = 0; cin = 1;
    #10 a = 0; b = 1; cin = 1;
    #10 a = 1; b = 0; cin = 1;
    #10 a = 1; b = 1; cin = 1;

end


initial begin


$monitor("a = %0h, b = %0h, cin = %0h, sum = %0h, co = %0h at time = `%0t",a,b,cin,summ,cout,$time); // gate level

    #200 $finish;
end 

endmodule
```

.

```
module FA_gatelevel(a, b, cin, summ, cout);

input a,b,cin;
output summ,cout;

FA_co ins_co(.a(a), .b(b), .cin(cin), .cout(cout));
FA_sum ins_sum(.a(a), .b(b), .cin(cin), .summ(summ));

endmodule
```

.

```
module FA_co (a, b, cin, cout);

input a, b, cin;
output cout;
wire ab, bc, ca;

and g0 (a,b,ab);
and g1 (b,c,bc);
and g2 (c,a,ca);
or  g3 (ab,bc,ca,cout);

endmodule
```

.

```
module FA_sum(a, b, cin, summ);

input a, b, cin;
output  summ;

xor g0 (a,b,cin,summ);


endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to Verilog gate-primitives, the output is always the first connection.